# Reaction of phenol with sulphuric acid and nitric acid

Tags: organic-chemistry

I'm confused a little bit about the products **A** and **B** .

[image: link for the image]

Please identify **A** and **B**

Comment: Could you us what you already did?

Comment: Hi S. Dutta, welcome to Chem.SE! We require you to show your efforts on this problem. What formulae/steps did you try? What knowledge do you already have about this? Where did you get stuck? Please add this to your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the reaction provided above is a better way to synthesize Picric acid(2,4,6-trinitrophenol).

First, when the phenol is reacted with concentrated $\ce{H2SO4}$ , it behaves like a normal sulphonation reaction at high temperatures. The major product at high temperature is **p-hydroxybenzenesulphonic acid**, although there is a small amount of o-hydroxy benzenesulphonic acid. So, you should write the **major product** in **A** which is **4-hydroxybenzenesulphonic acid**.

But, when **A** is treated with conc $\ce{HNO3}$, due to high activating property of $\ce{-OH}$ group, the $\ce{-NO2}$ groups are substituted at both the ortho positions.If both the ortho positions are substituted by $\ce{-NO2}$ group, there will be extensive intramolecular Hydrogen bonding , which makes this product thermodynamically very very stable ($\ce{$\Delta$H << 0)}$and at the higher temperatures the thermodynamically controlled product is formed in more amount.

More over, the $\ce{-NO2}$ groups also substitute the $\ce{-SO3H}$ groups at para position easily, because $\ce{H2SO4}$ being a stronger acid than $\ce{HNO3}$ ,the leaving $\ce{-SO3H}$ is more stable  than $\ce{-NO2}$. So, the ultimate product gets all ortho-para positions of phenol substituted by $\ce{-NO2}$ groups. 
 So, **B** will be  **PICRIC ACID(2,4,6 -trinitrophenol**)